# Why is the Java compiler (javac) case-insensitive when java (the interpreter) is case-sensitive?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm

When I was executing a Java program I noticed that the Java compiler is case-insensitive with respect to file names whereas the Java interpreter is case-sensitive.

The Java interpreter being case-sensitive is very much understandable as, the name of the class file  is the name of the class defined in the Java code.

Is there any good reason for the Java compiler being case-insensitive?

Comment: Do you execute the java compiler on a windows system? If so, there is your culprit, as Windows treats paths case insensitive.

Comment: If you try to run your program with `java MyProgram`, the command-line argument is a class name, not a file name.  And class names are case-sensitive in Java.  Is that the behavior you're asking about?  As for why file names are case insensitive--if you're on Windows, that's just how things are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows filesystem is case-insensitive.
You cannot (sanely) find a case-sensitive file on a case-insensitive filesystem.

If you run `javac` on Linux with a case-sensitive filesystem, it will be case-sensitive.

Comment: Windows is case-preserving, not case-insensitive.

Comment: @DavidConrad: Lookups are case-insensitive,

Comment: @DavidConrad If I correctly guess which distinction you're trying to make, then it's *sometimes* important but completely irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Yes, lookups are case insensitive, so you can look up `Foo.java` and find `foo.java` but the filesystem preserves the case of files that are stored in it -- if you create a file named `Foo.java` and do a directory traversal, you'll get `Foo.java` and not `FOO.JAVA` or `fOo.jAvA`. While this is not relevant to the question, the statement that the Windows filesystem is case-insensitive is false, and shouldn't be in a good answer.

Comment: @DavidConrad Case-preservation and case-sensitivity are commonly regarded as different properties. While case-sensitivity implies case-preservation, the opposite is not true. So windows filesystems currently are case-insensitive. The answer doesn't talk about case-preservation, so I regard it as perfectly correct.

Answer (score 3):

it depends on the underlying file system. Windows' file system is not case sensitive, so the when the java compiler looks for 'Foo.java', the OS will happily open 'foo.java' instead.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you're running the compiler on Windows or another operating system with either a case-preserving or case-insensitive filesystem. If you ran it on an OS that used a case-sensitive filesystem, you would get different results. In other words, it's not the compiler, it's the operating system (or rather, its filesystem).

Comment: Allow me to nitpick a bit - it is **not** the OS, it is the filesystem. You'll get the same errors when you're on Linux and work in a NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is still an OS for children and people that just want to surf the Web or do their fiscal paperwork. But not for developers.

Since almost 20 years, MS has done almost nothing with respect to:

- File systems (they could keep their beloved NTFS as default, and offer another one for professionals, could they not)
- Command line, it's still the same bad crap we got with Windows NT. Mind you, NT stands for "New Technology" and yet they didn't even manage to inherit what was already available for another 10 or 20 years.

Hence, if you develop Java, make sure you don't have class or package names that differ in case only. This will invariably lead to disaster.

Do yourself a favor, make a bit room on your HD, or attach an external one, and install a dual boot LINUX. If must be, make a virtual machine. You'll never look back, once you got your favored IDE installed. And you'll learn a bit or two along the way.

Comment: I think I deserve a thanks for giving you a space to vent your anger on Microsoft. 

Your advice taken I shall be moving to linux(ubuntu, preferrably), once I have a good command on JAVA.

Comment: @user2900314 No anger, just facts. Especially with Java. you're independent of OS (unless you need bindings to native stuff that is available on Windows only). You have the choice.

Comment: To be fair, they did add PowerShell in recent versions of Windows, although it is difficult, to say the least, to make it the default instead of `cmd.exe`: http://superuser.com/questions/608194/how-to-set-powershell-as-default-instead-of-cmd-exe

Comment: @DavidConrad That is why I didn't say they did nothing for developers. For sure they did! Think of Visual Studio. But, of course, it all smells a bit like "vendor lock in". And still, if I have VS and Powershell, I still miss lex, yacc, make, grep, perl, sed, you name it.

Comment: Yes, for sure. That's why when I'm using Windows I always have a Cygwin bash shell around. But this is off topic at this point. :)