# Compiling a .java file

Tags: java

I was compiling a .java file through the command line with the typical javac command. The file name was Test1.java, however, when I tried compiling test1.java there was no error. Why is this so?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a test1.java on the same directory?

Comment: Tell us exactly what you did. You know this might also have to do with the file system your OS is providing. Macs for example have some strange settings around casiness of file names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your operating system is case-insensitive.

See also answers to: [Why is the Java complier (javac) case-insensitive when java (the interpreter) is case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633521/why-is-the-java-complier-javac-case-insensitive-when-java-the-interpreter-is)

Comment: That helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Java language is case sensitive but the command line is not. Test.java is not the same as test.java in java but it's the same thing in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Windows filesystem is case-insensitive. that's why you are not getting error.
On *nix  if you use javac with case-sensitive then you will get error

Answer (score 0):

> May be you have test1.java and Test1.java both classes in the same
>   folder so it was compiling for both

Answer (score 0):

if you use platform that is case-insenstive such as: Windows that will work.
But if you are in platform that is case-senstive such as: UNIX-Based, please check if there is a file with lower-case in directory.